# Why remove element of Map?

Tags: java

I am filtering the all list which ahve same lat,long in one list and put into an same list and put that list into map My code is as:-

```
private Collection<List<Applicationdataset>> groupTheList(ArrayList<Applicationdataset> arrayList)
  {
    Map<Key, List<Applicationdataset>> map = new HashMap<Key, List<Applicationdataset>>();
    for(Applicationdataset appSet: arrayList)
       {
        Key key = new Key(appSet.getLatitude(), appSet.getLongitude());
        List<Applicationdataset> list = map.get(key);
        if(list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>();

        }
        list.add(appSet);
             map.put(key, list);
    }
    return map.values();
}


public class Key {
    String _lat;
    String _lon;

    Key(String lat, String lon) {
        _lat = lat;
        _lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Key key = (Key) o;

        if (!_lat.equals(key._lat)) return false;
        if (!_lon.equals(key._lon)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = _lat.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + _lon.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

But When I am debuging my code according to xml which come from web-service there is 2 list which have same lat long and they are saving in same list in amp at time of debuging but when I go next step of debug the element of map which have 2 item list decrease and showing size 1 I am unable to rectify this issue.

Comment: Maybe to other people, your question seems more sensible but at the moment I'm not entirely sure how to make head or tails of what you're asking. Could you please clarify what you're trying to do first? That might also help us understand what the problem you're experiencing is.

Comment: Actually My requirement is that I want to store all list of property which have same lat,long in one list from xml ,which xml coming from web-service for that I tryied above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK: You've overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` consistently.

Check for whitespace in the lat/lng values as the cause of your problems, perhaps `trim()` in the constructor:

```
Key(String lat, String lon) {
    _lat = lat.trim();
    _lon = lon.trim();
}
```

Also, you can simplify your code to this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Key
        && _lat.equals(((Key)o)._lat))
        && _lon.equals(((Key)o)._lon));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // String.hashCode() is sufficiently good for this addition to be acceptable
    return _lat.hashCode() + _lon.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. But I believe the issue is that you are using both latitude and longitude in Key hashCode()/equals() implementation thats why second Applicationdataset in your input list replaces the first one in your map object. You should implement the case when related list was already put into map and do not replace it.

Comment: Sorry for my explaination.But In first step of debugging  suppose first properties lat,long occure 2 times in list that is saving in list properly means showing list(L1) size in map is 2 , but when I iterate next step means loop  is running further 2-3 times size of arralist (L1) is showing 1 this is my issue..